# BinaryWriter Incorrectly writing two bytes extra C#

Tags: c#, hex, binarywriter

Firstly, here is my method to write to my specified offsets, I've went through the debugging process and everything is getting set accordingly.

Example, I've set the pokemonValue to `190` it is then converted to `0xBE` and then written to the offset at offsetArray[i] == `0x1D104` The expected behavior is that it will simply write 0xBE at this offset. It does not do that. instead it writes `0x02 0x42 0x45` at `0x1D104 0x1D105 0x1D106` respectively.

```
        public void writeStarterPokemon(long[] offsetArray, BinaryWriter writer, int pokemonValue)
        {
            string hexVal = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < offsetArray.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.BaseStream.Position = offsetArray[i];
                hexVal = string.Format("{0:X}", pokemonValue); // pokemonValue is a decimal ranging from 0-255;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hex val: 0x{0:1X}, Offset: 0x{1:X5}", hexVal, offsetArray[i])); // to see if the values are correct
                writer.Write(hexVal);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Here is an example of the array used and the how the method is called

```
private long[] squirtleOffsets = new long[] { 0x1D104, 0x1D11F, 0x24BA5, 0x26FBC};

writeStarterPokemon(sqrtlOffsets, writer, NameList.SelectedIndex); 
// NameList is the name of my comboBox populated with pokemon data, 0-255
```

I've checked my offsets and they are correct and earlier in the program I read from them which works as it is intended. So I'm unsure why this isn't working correctly or rather setting the data to be incorrect.

Comment: `BinaryWriter` prefixes strings with their length, that's where the 0x02 is coming from. It looks like what you want is to actually write the BINARY value, not a string at all. Is `pokemonValue` always in the range 0..255?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ah ok, that makes sense. Yes, it's always in that range.

Comment: In that case you could try `writer.Write((byte)pokemonValue);` - or use `writer.BaseStream.WriteByte((byte)pokemonValue);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson
`writer.BaseStream.WriteByte((byte)pokemonValue);` I have used this and it worked, thank you!!

Comment: @David it is not usually a good idea to mix and match APIs like that - in a lot of cases you'll get bitten by buffering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write specific bytes you need to use the `byte[]` etc APIs. If you use the `Write(string)` API, it encodes extra data for the string length etc, which you presumably *don't want*. Frankly, `BinaryWriter` is not very useful in most scenarios - you're better off writing to a `Stream` etc, which will limit you to APIs that *do what you expect*.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well, if you convert your string to a char array, it does not add the extra bytes.

```cs
writer.Write(hexVal.ToCharArray());
```